# Using regular expressions to do mass replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

If we have the following lines

```
<something>A<else>
<something>B<else>
<something>C<else>
```

Using regular expressions in Notepad++ how to remove all and keeps the letters to be

```
A
B
C
```

I've used to replce `(.*)(>)(.*)` by `\3` but didn't worked so anyway what would be the command if i want remove all (things) before (something) and all (things) after.

Thanks

Comment: Voted to close. While regular expressions are often used in software development, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dear Manal Nor, welcome to Stack Overflow!

I achieved the above result using the following code in Notepad++ 5.6.8:

"FIND WHAT":

```
<[^>]+>([^<]*)<[^>]+>
```

"REPLACE WITH":

```
\1
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank you all, the thread commands are working perfect, this will save a lot of my time.

Comment: @Manal Nor you should mark SoreThumbs answer as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark beside his answer.

Answer (score 1):

try search `^.*>(.*)<.*$` and replace `\1`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the program here but try something like replacing

```
 .*>(.*)<.*
```

with

```
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with:

```
(<.*>)(.*)(<.*>)

\2
```

and that seemed to work for me.

or just

```
<.*>(.*)<.*>

\1
```